# Using custom class with vectors: 'std::vector' default constructor error

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm trying to create one class which defines an Item and another class which defines an Inventory, containing a vector list of Items. However, with the solution below, I'm getting multiple errors, most notably

```
'std::vector': no appropriate default constructor available
```

...and others which I can only assume lead on from that. Here's my definitions:

**header.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Item.h"
#include "Inventory.h"
```

**Item.h**

```
#include "header.h"
class Item
{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    Item(std::string n, std::string d, int c);
    std::string getName();
};
```

**Item.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

Item::Item(string n)
{
    name = n;
}

string Item::getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

**Inventory.h**

```
#include "header.h"

class Inventory
{
private:
    std::vector<Item> itemlist;

public:
    Inventory();
    std::string getInventory();
    void addItem(Item x);
};
```

**Inventory.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

Inventory::Inventory()
{
}

string Inventory::getInventory()
{
    string output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= itemlist.size(); i++)
    {
        output = output.append(itemlist[i].getName());
    }

    return output;
}

void Inventory::addItem(Item x)
{
    itemlist.push_back(x);
}
```

I have a feeling it's something to do with my custom-defined object being somehow incompatible with vectors in the way I've attempted to use them. Is there something fundamentally wrong with all of this or have I just made a simple mistake somewhere?

Adding in a default constructor changed nothing, but adding in a `: itemlist(0)` initialiser to the Inventory constructor removed that particular error. However, multiple instances of these two error still occur:

```
'Item': undeclared identifier
```

and

```
'std::vector': 'Item' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
```

I'm wondering if there's some sort of scope issue happening here as regards to my two separate classes?

Comment: It's pretty clear from the error message, to use your class as vector item, you need to provide a default constructor. If you can't provide one use a `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr<>`  of your class stored in the vector.

Comment: you are better off putting shared_ptrs into the vector rather than the object themselves (that leads to lots of copying and cloning)

Comment: This isn't the issue, but `Item.h` includes `header.h`, which includes `Item.h`, and there appear to be no include guards present...

Comment: `inventory.h` needs to include `item.h`

Comment: Ah, the recursive dependency between the header files was indeed the root of all the evil. No wonder it was getting its knickers in such a twist.

Comment: It's not a good idea to put the update-EDIT before the actual question, it confuses those of us who haven't read the previous version.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a default constructor to use std::vector. The default constructor is the one that has no arguments, i.e., `Item::Item() { ... }`

Comment: I've added in both a default constructor function and its prototype:
`Item();
Item(std::string n, std::string d, int c);`
...and...
`Item::Item() {}
Item::Item(string n, string d, int c)
{
 name = n;}`

But the same error still occurs. If I also add an initialiser to the Inventory constructor like so:
`Inventory::Inventory() : itemlist(0)
{
}`
That particular error disappears, but I still get multiple errors all along the line of `'Item': undeclared identifier` and `'std::vector': 'Item' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'` - is there some sort of scope problem going on?

Comment: @JosephParkins you have a cyclic dependency in your include files, as pointed out by R.Kapp.

Comment: The compiler will not generate a default constructor if another (non-default) constructor has been provided. A default constructor is only created by the compiler if no constructor has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in `std::vector<>`s [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (emphasis mine):

> **T** The type of the elements.
>         must meet the requirements of **CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible**.
>   The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that **element type is a complete type** and meets the requirements of Erasable, but many member functions impose stricter requirements.

So you still need to provide a copy constructor and assignment operator as well. Also `Item` needs to be completely declared, when `vector<Item>` is instantiated.

---

You can store a smart pointer in your `vector` though, if it's not possible to provide the required functions for your class, e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> itemlist;
```

or

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>> itemlist;
```

This would have the advantage that you don't have your `Item` instances copied all the time.