# C++ vector has ownership of object

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to understand how to model ownership properly in C++, and I'm having trouble precisely understanding who owns what when.

For example I had a class like this, with a very complex init list and complex members who also have complex init lists.

```
class ComplexClass {

public:

  OtherComplexClass1 foo1;
  OtherComplexClass2 foo2;
  //...
  OtherComplexClassN fooN;

  ComplexClass(
      int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) :
      foo1(OtherComplexClass1{arg1,arg2}),
      foo2(OtherComplexClass2{arg3}),
      //...
      fooN(OtherComplexClassN{foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4})
      {};
};
```

Using this I was able to allocate like so

```
auto my_class = ComplexClass(1,2,3);
```

and use the class fine. However now I want to make a dynamic number of these so I tried this

```
auto my_vec = std::vector<ComplexClass>{};
my_vec.emplace_back(ComplexClass{1,2,3});
```

But doing this I had a lot of memory errors. When I instead do

```
auto my_vec = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ComplexClass>>{};
my_vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<ComplexClass>(1,2,3));
```

everything seems to be working. My question is, why does the second way work and not the first?

Thank you

EDIT:

1. Added more precise description of error(s)
2. Added more precise example of object structure

(1) I actually have two scenarios. One is the one I described

```
auto my_vec = std::vector<ComplexClass>{};
my_vec.emplace_back(ComplexClass{1,2,3});
```

with the code in a free function (catch2 test).
The other is where I actually have the above, but inside the constructor of a holding class.
In the first case I get
`==60617==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free`
indicating a member function of one of the complex classes. In the second case I get `==60565==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free` indicating a `std::dequeue` member of one of the complex classes.

(2) The ComplexClass and OtherComplexClassK tree goes a few levels deep, and many members somewhere in the tree are references to other members in the tree. Maybe that's causing the problem? I have made sure that all references are references to a member that is ultimately constructed in an init list.

The remarks so far have been very helpful.

Comment: Saying "But doing this I had a lot of memory errors." is not a useful statement. Explain what you mean by that.

Comment: I would assume CompleClass internally doesn't handle copying/moving correctly. When using a vector of pointers, these bugs won't show as it stays on the same memory location.

Comment: It's very difficult give a useful answer without a full compiling example. I understand that your code is complex, but if you try to simplify it, maybe you can intercept the problem.

Comment: Sidenote: Instead of `my_vec.emplace_back(ComplexClass{1,2,3});` do `my_vec.emplace_back(1, 2, 3);`

Comment: @Strick good point.

Comment: @Viktor I agree that's probably the case. I don't need these classes to be copyable so maybe a unique_ptr<> is the better design anyway?

Answer (score 4):

Your class should be default-constructible, copy-assignable and copy-constructible. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33110129/5132939 for more details. Also it's desired to make it move-constuctible and move-assignable. In some cases std::vector will use move semantics instead of copy.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate initialisation does not comply with user-declared constructors.